# How can I resize a picture in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, size

I'm using kivy and I am trying to make a program to help me remember the super saiyans transformations. I wanted the buttons to be pictures instead of words. So here is the code I used to make the button a picture:

```
self.Goku = Button(background_normal = '106-1060675_goku-base-form-png-clipart (1).png')
self.Goku.bind(on_press = self.SonGoku)
self.add_widget(self.Goku)
```

When I runned the code to see what it looks like, I saw that one of the picture was to big and one to small. So I tried to resize the picture by adding size = ("10, 10") but it didn't work. I tried the same thing with size_hint, but it had the same result. Nothing moved. I looked at some documentations about the button and adding pictures to kivy but it didn't help much. Here's the entire code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class main(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 4

        self.Goku = Button(background_normal = '106-1060675_goku-base-form-png-clipart (1).png', size_hint = (1, 0.5))
        self.Goku.bind(on_press = self.SonGoku)
        self.add_widget(self.Goku)

        self.Vegeta = Button(background_normal = 'vegeta-png-clip-art.png', size_hint = (1, 1))
        self.Vegeta.bind(on_press = self.PrinceVegeta)
        self.add_widget(self.Vegeta)

    def SonGoku(self, instance):
        self.cols = 1

        self.remove_widget(self.Goku)
        self.remove_widget(self.Vegeta)

        self.NormalGoku = Button(text = "Base form")
        self.add_widget(self.NormalGoku)
        self.SSJGoku = Button(text = "Super saiyan")
        self.add_widget(self.SSJGoku)
        self.SSJ2Goku = Button(text = "Super saiyan 2")
        self.add_widget(self.SSJ2Goku)

    def PrinceVegeta(self, instance):
        self.cols = 1

        self.remove_widget(self.Goku)
        self.remove_widget(self.Vegeta)

        self.NormalVegeta = Button(text = "Base form")
        self.add_widget(self.NormalVegeta)
        self.SSJVegeta = Button(text = "Super saiyan")
        self.add_widget(self.SSJVegeta)
        self.SSJ2Vegeta = Button(text = "Super saiyan 2")
        self.add_widget(self.SSJ2Vegeta)

class Saiyan(App):
    def build(self):
        return main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Saiyan().run()
```

Help would be appreciated. Feel free to ask any question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be to draw the image on the buttons canvas. the attributes "allow_stretch" and "keep_ratio" are used to fill the entire button size.

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
```

Then:

```
self.Goku = Button(size_hint=(None, None), size=(120,120))
with self.Goku.canvas:
    Image(source='vegeta-png-clip-art.png', size=self.Goku.size, pos=self.Goku.pos, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
self.add_widget(self.Goku)
```

In case you are not setting the size explicitly for the button you need to bind the size attribute to a method in order to resize the image.

example:

```
class main(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 4
        self.Goku = Button()
        with self.Goku.canvas:
            self.Goku_img = Image(source='vegeta-png-clip-art.png', size=self.Goku.size, pos=self.Goku.pos, allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)
        self.Goku.bind(size=self.adjust_size)
        self.add_widget(self.Goku)

...

    def adjust_size(self, instance, value):
        self.Goku_img.size = value
```

I hope this is a suitable approach for you.

Comment: Do I need to import something to use size adjust?

Comment: No, you only need to import the Image class, the adjust_size method only takes the parameters from the bind method. Add this function to your main(GridLayout) class.

Comment: I added it but then when I run it , it makes this:AttributeError: 'main' object has no attribute 'adjust_size'

Comment: where? The comment box is not big enough

Comment: Update your post or simply reply in an answer or pastebin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212984/discussion-between-misternox-and-user116541).